# Enable/Disable ribbon button based on MailItem subject (Outlook VSTO)

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I have some trouble with a very simple VSTO AddIn.
I added two custom Ribbons via Designer (Ribbon1 and Ribbon2) in order to create a custom button on two built-in ribbons (`Microsoft.Outlook.Mail.Read` and `Microsoft.Outlook.Explorer`).
I would like to set the "Enabled" property of the ribbon buttons based on the selected mail's subject.
It works nice in the Explorer window/ribbon, but i can't solve it in the Inspector window.

The problem is that Outlook generates Inspector's Ribbon only once, so when I open in the inspector window another mail, I cannot change the state of the button. I tried Invalidate() method and using Ribbon XML with getEnabled, but I don't succeed. What is the problem?

```
namespace ApproveReport
{
    public partial class ThisAddIn
    {
        // Explorer object
        Outlook.Explorer ThisExplorer;

        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            // SelectionChange Event
            ThisExplorer = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer();
            ThisExplorer.SelectionChange += new Outlook.ExplorerEvents_10_SelectionChangeEventHandler(ThisExplorer_SelectionChange);
        }

        private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            // Empty
        }

        public void ThisExplorer_SelectionChange()
        {
            if(ThisExplorer.Selection.Count == 1)
            {
                Outlook.MailItem OriginalMessage = ThisExplorer.Selection[1];

                if (OriginalMessage.Subject.Contains("Report"))
                {
                    Globals.Ribbons.Ribbon1.buttonApproveReport.Enabled = true;
                    Globals.Ribbons.Ribbon2.buttonApproveReport.Enabled = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    Globals.Ribbons.Ribbon1.buttonApproveReport.Enabled = false;
                    Globals.Ribbons.Ribbon2.buttonApproveReport.Enabled = false;
                }
            }
         }
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your code that invalidates the ribbon? What is your code that handles getEnabled callback?

You must explicitly call Invalidate() when the selection changes for the explorer. You must do the same every time `Inspectors.NewInspector` event fires for the items shown in an inspector.

Comment: I added a NewInspector event with the line      Globals.Ribbons.Ribbon1.RibbonUI.Invalidate();. That is the first line in my event, after that I try to set the enabled property of my button.
The code runs properly (I tested with MessageBoxes), but the enable methods don't have any effect on my button! What should I do? I didn't succeed to implement XML Ribbon solution with getEnabled...

Comment: Again, post your code that shows getEnabled and other methods.

Comment: Based on your reply I managed to solve it, the event handler you suggested was the key...

So the correct order of the events:
1.) NewInspector Event,
2.) Check MailItem Subject, store the enabled/disabled state in a bool variable,
3.) Invalidate Ribbon,
4.) Run Enable action via getEnabled, set bool's value as button state.

Thanks again!

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko I have a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61149776/1232087) on my `VSTO AddIn` project for `WORD`. I was wondering if you would have time for a comment/suggestion etc.